# Problems with a new hydro install of hector quadrotor demo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I observe the following when trying to test out the new version of the most excellent [hector_quad_rotor](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor) `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-hector-quadrotor-demo`.

```
user@happyplace:~$ roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo outdoor_flight_gazebo.launch 
... logging to /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/297f0af6-c010-11e3-8a21-fa163eaa4736/roslaunch-10-100-16-5-23452.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid <arg> tag: hector_quadrotor_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks. 

Arg xml is <arg name="model" value="$(find hector_quadrotor_description)/urdf/quadrotor_hokuyo_utm30lx.gazebo.xacro"/>
```

It seems that `ros-hydro-hector-quadrotor-description` should be a dependency. Can anyone else confirm this experience?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151231/problems-with-a-new-hydro-install-of-hector-quadrotor-demo/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2014-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I get the same error

solved running

sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-hector*

all hector_quadrotor packages will be installed, then gazebo can find the right one

ciao!

thanks

---

Originally posted by [RiccardoLasagno](https://answers.ros.org/users/12766/riccardolasagno/) with karma: 26 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2014-04-10**:
Ok. That's good to know! I don't have a physical quadrotor personally, so I did not install the entire hector package as I thought it would be overkill.  Running sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-hector-quadrotor-demo ros-hydro-hector-quadrotor-description was the path that I tried.